# The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure - NET Core WebAPI

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, https, ssl-certificate

I'm struggling when putting together two ASP.Net Core application talk to each other using HTTPS.

Before setting up the web api, I first generated the HTTPS correspondent certificates through a development private PKI. This is the code to build the client and server certificates. I believe that the PKI part of the code is not relevant for now.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

printf "SET ENVIRONMENT\n\n"

export ca_dir=$HOME/CA
root_ca_config_path=$ca_dir/root-ca/root-ca.conf
sub_ca_config_path=$ca_dir/sub-ca/sub-ca.conf
server_config_path=$ca_dir/server/server_config.conf
client_config_path=$ca_dir/client/client_config.conf
pass=$ca_dir/pass/pass.aes256

printf "CREATED CLIENT FOLDER\n\n"

mkdir -p $ca_dir/client/{certs,private,csr}

printf "CREATED SERIAL\n\n"

openssl rand -hex 16 > $ca_dir/ca-chain/ca-chain.srl

cat << EOF > $server_config_path
basicConstraints        = critical, CA:FALSE
subjectKeyIdentifier    = hash
authorityKeyIdentifier  = keyid:always, issuer:always
keyUsage                = critical, nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment, keyAgreement 
extendedKeyUsage        = critical, serverAuth
subjectAltName          = @alt_names

[ alt_names ]
# Be sure to include the domain name here because Common Name is not so commonly honoured by itself
DNS.1 = localhost 
IP.1 = 127.0.0.1

[ req ]
# Options for the req tool, man req.
default_bits   = 2048
distinguished_name  = req_distinguished_name
string_mask   = utf8only
default_md   =  sha256

[ req_distinguished_name ]
countryName                     = BR
stateOrProvinceName             = State or Province Name
localityName                    = Locality Name
0.organizationName              = Organization Name
organizationalUnitName          = Organization Unit Name
commonName                      = Common Name
emailAddress                    = Email Address
countryName_default  = BR
stateOrProvinceName_default = Brazil
0.organizationName_default = ElectricStone Ltd
organizationalUnitName_default = FakeProvider
commonName_default = localhost
EOF

cat << EOF > $client_config_path
basicConstraints        = critical, CA:FALSE
subjectKeyIdentifier    = hash
authorityKeyIdentifier  = keyid:always, issuer:always
keyUsage                = critical, nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
extendedKeyUsage        = critical, clientAuth
subjectAltName          = @alt_names

[ req ]
# Options for the req tool, man req.
default_bits   = 2048
distinguished_name  = req_distinguished_name
string_mask   = utf8only
default_md   =  sha256

[ req_distinguished_name ]
countryName                     = BR
stateOrProvinceName             = State or Province Name
localityName                    = Locality Name
0.organizationName              = Organization Name
organizationalUnitName          = Organization Unit Name
commonName                      = Common Name
emailAddress                    = Email Address
countryName_default  = BR
stateOrProvinceName_default = Brazil
0.organizationName_default = ElectricStone Ltd
organizationalUnitName_default = eCommerce
commonName_default = localhost

[ alt_names ]
# Be sure to include the domain name here because Common Name is not so commonly honoured by itself
DNS.1 = localhost 
IP.1 = 127.0.0.1
EOF

printf "CREATING SERVER PRIVATE KEY...\n\n"

openssl genrsa -out $ca_dir/server/private/netwebapp.key 2048

printf "CREATING CLIENT PRIVATE KEY...\n\n"

openssl genrsa -out $ca_dir/client/private/netwebappclient.key 2048

printf "CREATING A SERVER SIGNING REQUEST...\n\n"

openssl req -config $server_config_path -passin file:$pass -key $ca_dir/server/private/netwebapp.key \
-new -sha256 -out $ca_dir/server/csr/netwebapp.csr

printf "CREATING A CLIENT SIGNING REQUEST...\n\n"

openssl req -config $client_config_path -passin file:$pass -key $ca_dir/client/private/netwebappclient.key \
-new -sha256 -out $ca_dir/client/csr/netwebappclient.csr

printf "CREATING THE SERVER CERTIFICATE...\n\n"

openssl x509 -req -in $ca_dir/server/csr/netwebapp.csr -passin file:$pass \
-CA $ca_dir/ca-chain/ca-chain.crt \
-CAkey $ca_dir/sub-ca/private/sub-ca.key \
-CAserial $ca_dir/ca-chain/ca-chain.srl \
-out $ca_dir/server/certs/netwebapp.crt -days 365 -sha256 -extfile $server_config_path

printf "CREATING THE CLIENT CERTFICATE...\n\n"

openssl x509 -req -in $ca_dir/client/csr/netwebappclient.csr -passin file:$pass \
-CA $ca_dir/ca-chain/ca-chain.crt \
-CAkey $ca_dir/sub-ca/private/sub-ca.key \
-CAserial $ca_dir/ca-chain/ca-chain.srl \
-out $ca_dir/client/certs/netwebappclient.crt -days 365 -sha256 -extfile $client_config_path
```

After I had generate the certificates I was able to test their effectiveness through respectively openssl commands:

```sh
# Testing the server certificate

sudo openssl s_server -accept 443 -www -key $ca_dir/server/private/netwebapp.key \
-CAfile $ca_dir/sub-ca/certs/sub-ca.crt \
-cert $ca_dir/server/certs/netwebapp.crt

# Testing the client certificate

openssl s_client -connect localhost:443 -servername localhost \
-cert /home/dggt/CA/client/certs/netwebappclient.crt \
-key /home/dggt/CA/client/private/netwebappclient.key \
-CAfile /home/dggt/CA/root-ca/certs/ca.crt \
-showcerts
```

Those test command produced this output at client side:

```
CONNECTED(00000006)
depth=2 C = BR, ST = Brazil, O = ElectricStone Ltd, CN = ElectricStone Root CA
verify return:1
depth=1 C = BR, ST = Brazil, O = ElectricStone Ltd, CN = ElectricStone SUB CA
verify return:1
depth=0 C = BR, ST = Brazil, O = ElectricStone Ltd, OU = FakeProvider, CN = localhost
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:C = BR, ST = Brazil, O = ElectricStone Ltd, OU = FakeProvider, CN = localhost
   i:C = BR, ST = Brazil, O = ElectricStone Ltd, CN = ElectricStone SUB CA
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

################################## Output suppressed ##################################

-----END CERTIFICATE-----
 1 s:C = BR, ST = Brazil, O = ElectricStone Ltd, CN = ElectricStone SUB CA
   i:C = BR, ST = Brazil, O = ElectricStone Ltd, CN = ElectricStone Root CA
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

################################## Output suppressed ##################################

-----END CERTIFICATE-----
---
Server certificate
subject=C = BR, ST = Brazil, O = ElectricStone Ltd, OU = FakeProvider, CN = localhost

issuer=C = BR, ST = Brazil, O = ElectricStone Ltd, CN = ElectricStone SUB CA

---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA256
Peer signature type: RSA-PSS
Server Temp Key: X25519, 253 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 3378 bytes and written 381 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, TLSv1.3, Cipher is TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
---
Post-Handshake New Session Ticket arrived:
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.3
    Cipher    : TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    Session-ID: 5D3176780DE3404A9E246E026D875B0B81A3EFE9EB7B2F17D24E3565DB42E1AE
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Resumption PSK: E9D6B7E66063C4969C203A153A3E60E1131095E2AE1569AE04673BA9F1FA90974ACE42D5B902ABE8A5760218AD2959FF
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 7200 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:

################################## Output suppressed ##################################

    Start Time: 1605522448
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
    Extended master secret: no
    Max Early Data: 0
---
read R BLOCK
---
Post-Handshake New Session Ticket arrived:
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.3
    Cipher    : TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    Session-ID: 5B8E394EBEBEBC7FD2617EA0695CD9C2E0B8F4ED733F628CA28A5190AB4D27BA
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Resumption PSK: F536C3428049C2DD6F9496D14E516B30611D2D7056AE6B87445F6328B4B1577093FDA3D4A6AC9D00F30F7725B6925A9E
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 7200 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:

################################## Output suppressed ##################################

    Start Time: 1605522448
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
    Extended master secret: no
    Max Early Data: 0
---
read R BLOCK
DONE
```

So far so good. However at ASP.NET Core side the thing get complicated.
Afterwards some research, at one of my API, I configured the built-in Kestrel web server to work with HTTPS by the following code:

Program.cs

```cs
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace BogusProvider
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel((context, options) =>
                    {
                        var certificateConfig = context.Configuration.GetSection("Certificate");
                        var certFileName = certificateConfig["FileName"];
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER")))
                        {
                            // Insert a Docker entry coming from user-secrets when development in container
                            certFileName = certificateConfig["Docker"];
                        }

                        var certPassword = certificateConfig["Password"];
                        // Configure the Url and ports to bind to
                        // This overrides calls to UseUrls and the ASPNETCORE_URLS environment variable, but will be 
                        // overridden if you call UseIisIntegration() and host behind IIS/IIS Express
                        // When development in container, use ListenAnyIP method
                        options.ConfigureHttpsDefaults(adapterOptions =>
                        {
                            adapterOptions.CheckCertificateRevocation = false;
                            adapterOptions.ClientCertificateMode = ClientCertificateMode.RequireCertificate;
                        });
                        options.ListenAnyIP(5002, listenOptions =>
                        {
                            listenOptions.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http2;
                            listenOptions.UseHttps(certFileName, certPassword);
                            listenOptions.UseConnectionLogging("FakerHttpsConnection");
                        });
                    }).UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
}
```

I also installed the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Certificate package in order to setup the certificate authentication in the ASP.NET Core machinery.

This is a snippet of code at Startup.cs:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers();
    services.AddAuthentication(CertificateAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddCertificate();
    // Others services suppressed
}
```

With all this code running, I get 'connection refused' when either requesting through the browser (after I have installed the client certificate alongside its private key password and the Sub CA by browser settings) or the other Web API when requesting through HttpClient.

This is my HttpClient code:

```cs
var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.ClientCertificates.Add(new X509Certificate2("/home/dggt/CA/client/certs/netwebappclient.pfx",
    "pa$$worD_1"));
return new HttpClient(handler) {BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:5002/fake/")};
```

This the gist of the error message at console:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
 ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
```

System Specs:

- OS: Ubuntu 20.04
- Net Info:

  - SDK: 3.1.404
  - Runtime: Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.10

Any idea of what I might be doing wrong? Any help is welcome!